# How to get the label value of the clicked bar on HorizontalBarChart in MPAndroidChart?

Tags: java, android, charts

I am using **HorizontalBarChart** by **com.github.PhilJay:MPAndroidChart:v2.2.5**. I want to get the string values of the bar(label value) which I clicked.

This is my yAxis. I have 7 bars.

```
chart = (HorizontalBarChart) vLayout.findViewById(R.id.hchart);

final ArrayList<String> xAxis = new ArrayList<>();
        xAxis.add("FG0028");
        xAxis.add("FG0010");
        xAxis.add("FG0009");
        xAxis.add("FG0005");
        xAxis.add("FG0004");
        xAxis.add("FG0002");
        xAxis.add("FG0001");
```

I want to get the label value of the bar i click, for example **FG0028**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you try to implement OnChartValueSelectedListener present in the mpandroidchart library

```
@Override
public void onNothingSelected() {
    Log.d("Nothing selected", "Nothing selected.");
}

@Override
public void onValueSelected(Entry e, int dataSetIndex, Highlight h) {
   Log.d("Entry selected", e.toString());
     Log.d("", "low: " + mChart.getLowestVisibleXIndex() + ", high: "    + mChart.getHighestVisibleXIndex());
  }
```

Comment: thank you very much. I can find a way using this answer.

Comment: Hi @user5974345 , can you show further. overriding onValueSelected how did you display Data values on Data points? Did you used lineDataset inside it?